# Troubleshooting HDMI Switch with New Machine

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi

I use an [HDMI switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079JQ9XXV) to change whether my work computer or personal computer outputs to my monitor.

I recently built a new personal computer that leverages an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti graphics cards. When I try and connect the new machine to my display via the HDMI switch I get a black screen. I did some searching online and found that the refresh rate of the output needs to match the HDMI switch's and I verified that my switch supports 60Hz and that I'm outputting at 60Hz.

Any other ideas about what could be causing the issue? I've tried different HDMI cables, but the one I'm using worked fine on my old personal computer. Note that the display is outputted fine when directly connecting personal PC to monitor via the HDMI cable.

My previous personal computer used a much older NVIDIA GTX 700 series if that helps explain lack of compatibility.

Both my old personal machine and my new one are outputting at 4K resolution and the switch supports that.

Comment: do you have any adapters inline, like DP -> HDMI? if so they should be active adapters when using a device like this.

Comment: Wait, I think this question acted as a rubber duck debugging. I was looking at HDMI switch page and it only supports 30Hz at 4K! I'm guessing my older video card outputted at 30Hz on 4K resolution. Going to try buying a switch that supports 60Hz 4K

Comment: @thatidiotguy - [This](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07KJV6Y7P/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) is a 4k 60Hz DisplayPort product that I can confirm is wonderful.  I am sure they sell similar models that are the appropriate revision of HDMI that supports 4k@60Hz.  Yes; I would agree the switch itself is the problem, you could try using the appropriate revision of HDMI cables and see if that helps.

Comment: @thatidiotguy you are LEGEND!  I've been stressing over why my HDMI switch wouldn't accept some devices, even though they were fine direct to monitor... changed one such device to 30hz and hey presto, it's like magic. . THANK YOU